# List of error cases in use _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[UserManager.CreateAsync Method (TUser, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497540(v=vs.108).aspx) doesn't mention about errors.

In controller, I jsut edit something like:

```
public async Task<ObjectResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> value = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    value["Success"] = false;
    value["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            value["Success"] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            value["ErrorMessage"] = result.Errors;
        }    
    }

    return new ObjectResult(value);
}
```

In client:

```
$scope.registerForm_submit = function ($event, account) {
    $event.preventDefault();

    if (registerForm.isValid(account)) {

        // registerForm.collectData returns new FormData() which contains
        // email, password, confirmpassword, agreement, returnurl...

        let formData = registerForm.collectData(account),                
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                let data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

                if (data['Success']) {
                    window.location = '/'
                } else {                        
                    if (data['ErrorMessage'][0]['code'] === 'DuplicateUserName') {
                        let li = angular.element('<li/>').text(`Email ${account['email']} already exists.`);
                        angular.element('div[data-valmsg-summary=true] ul').html(li);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        xhttp.open('POST', '/account/register');
        xhttp.send(formData);
    }
};
```

I've tried to register new account with an existing email and got the code:

```
data['ErrorMessage'][0]['code'] === 'DuplicateUserName'
```

My question: how to check other cases?

Comment: I would assume, if you're using the templated versions of ASP.NET Identity, that what you're after is these: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs

Comment: @TiesonT. Exactly what I'm looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: Actually, that previous link was for ASP.NET Core Identity, which isn't _exactly_ the same as ASP.NET Identity. Looks like the latter's error codes are defined here: https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Resources.Designer.cs - they appear to be the same, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error codes defined in ASP.NET Identity are found at https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Resources.Designer.cs - I've extracted them out to this list:

- DefaultError
- DuplicateEmail
- DuplicateName
- ExternalLoginExists
- InvalidEmail
- InvalidToken
- InvalidUserName
- LockoutNotEnabled
- NoTokenProvider
- NoTwoFactorProvider
- PasswordMismatch
- PasswordRequireDigit
- PasswordRequireLower
- PasswordRequireNonLetterOrDigit
- PasswordRequireUpper
- PasswordTooShort
- PropertyTooShort
- RoleNotFound
- StoreNotIQueryableRoleStore
- StoreNotIQueryableUserStore
- StoreNotIUserClaimStore
- StoreNotIUserConfirmationStore
- StoreNotIUserEmailStore
- StoreNotIUserLockoutStore
- StoreNotIUserLoginStore
- StoreNotIUserPasswordStore
- StoreNotIUserPhoneNumberStore
- StoreNotIUserRoleStore
- StoreNotIUserSecurityStampStore
- StoreNotIUserTwoFactorStore
- UserAlreadyHasPassword
- UserAlreadyInRole
- UserIdNotFound
- UserNameNotFound
- UserNotInRole

ASP.NET Core Identity has these codes defined:

- DefaultError
- ConcurrencyFailure
- PasswordMismatch
- InvalidToken
- LoginAlreadyAssociated
- InvalidUserName
- InvalidEmail
- DuplicateUserName
- DuplicateEmail
- InvalidRoleName
- DuplicateRoleName
- UserAlreadyHasPassword
- UserLockoutNotEnabled
- UserAlreadyInRole
- UserNotInRole
- PasswordTooShort
- PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric
- PasswordRequiresDigit
- PasswordRequiresLower
- PasswordRequiresUpper

So, it's possible that not all of the former error codes will actually show up in an IdentityResult. I don't use either, so this is just what I gather from skimming the available source code. Caveat emptor...

Seems like this should be documented somewhere...

I like to have strings of this nature defined in one place, so I typically do something like:

```
public class IdentityErrorCodes
{
    public const string DefaultError                    = "DefaultError";
    public const string ConcurrencyFailure              = "ConcurrencyFailure";
    public const string PasswordMismatch                = "PasswordMismatch";
    public const string InvalidToken                    = "InvalidToken";
    public const string LoginAlreadyAssociated          = "LoginAlreadyAssociated";
    public const string InvalidUserName                 = "InvalidUserName";
    public const string InvalidEmail                    = "InvalidEmail";
    public const string DuplicateUserName               = "DuplicateUserName";
    public const string DuplicateEmail                  = "DuplicateEmail";
    public const string InvalidRoleName                 = "InvalidRoleName";
    public const string DuplicateRoleName               = "DuplicateRoleName";
    public const string UserAlreadyHasPassword          = "UserAlreadyHasPassword";
    public const string UserLockoutNotEnabled           = "UserLockoutNotEnabled";
    public const string UserAlreadyInRole               = "UserAlreadyInRole";
    public const string UserNotInRole                   = "UserNotInRole";
    public const string PasswordTooShort                = "PasswordTooShort";
    public const string PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric = "PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric";
    public const string PasswordRequiresDigit           = "PasswordRequiresDigit";
    public const string PasswordRequiresLower           = "PasswordRequiresLower";
    public const string PasswordRequiresUpper           = "PasswordRequiresUpper";

    public static string[] All = { 
        DefaultError,
        ConcurrencyFailure,
        PasswordMismatch,
        InvalidToken,
        LoginAlreadyAssociated,
        InvalidUserName,
        InvalidEmail,
        DuplicateUserName,
        DuplicateEmail,
        InvalidRoleName,
        DuplicateRoleName,
        UserAlreadyHasPassword,
        UserLockoutNotEnabled,
        UserAlreadyInRole,
        UserNotInRole,
        PasswordTooShort,
        PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric,
        PasswordRequiresDigit,
        PasswordRequiresLower,
        PasswordRequiresUpper 
    };
}
```

This lets you be consistent in the keys you're using as lookups, and the last field, `All`, gives you an array you can enumerate through, if necessary.

Using your code, you can do this:

```
if(data['ErrorMessage'][0]['code'] == IdentityErrorCodes.DuplicateUserName)
{
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Lost 1 case in my example: `DuplicateUserName`.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core? I did add the error codes I found there, which does include DuplicateUserName. Otherwise, it's possible the UserManager has some magic strings defined somewhere...

Comment: Yes. I'm using asp.net core. The update is match the case. Thanks!

Comment: Why create the array that basically repeats what's already there? This can already give you the classes properties as list: `IdentityErrorCodes.GetType().GetProperties();`... Just punch it on a method.

Answer (score 14):

For ASP.NET Core [you can find](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs) the different error types in the `IdentityErrorDescriber` class under the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`.

As you [can see](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs#L131), the error codes are generated via `nameof()`, e.g:

```
Code = nameof(DuplicateUserName)
```

So you could also use that for your cases:

```
data['ErrorMessage'][0]['code'] == nameof(IdentityErrorDescriber.DuplicateUserName)
```

This way you don't have to curate a list of error codes as suggested in another answer to your question.

Comment: The problem is regarding the use of those error codes inside an Ajax code... not within the controller.

Comment: The repo has been moved [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs)